# Install only form controls styles from Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

Is there a way to install just the form control styles (input-group ect) from Bootstrap 4?

I found a resource where you can only install the [Bootstrap 4 Grid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-4-grid). Is there a similar resource for installing just the form styles?

Answer (score 0):

Take the css form the form style of the boostrap. for example the form-control styles.

```
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 36px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #555555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccd0d2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
}
```

of course you need to do some extra work for the .js validation but hey, it's one solution.